# The two methods for key mapping in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I find that there are two ways to set key in emacs: golbal-set-key and define-key.
Are they the same? Or is there any pros/cons between the two approaches?

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-f") 'my-find-file)
(define-key global-map
  "\C-ck" 'hello)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's effectively no difference, if you look at the definition of `global-set-key` you'll see:

```
(define-key (current-global-map) key command)
```

It's possible that `(current-global-map)` will return a keymap that is different than `global-key-map`, but unusual.

Now, since `define-key` takes an argument of a keymap, it is obviously more flexible than the simple `global-set-key`.  For details on keymaps check out the [info pages](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keymaps.html).

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `(global-set-key)` or `(local-set-key)` find out the global / local map for you (before calling `(define-key)`).

**Edit** You can use `M-x describe-function` for `(global-set-key)`

```
(global-set-key key command)

Give key a global binding as command.
command is the command definition to use; usually it is
a symbol naming an interactively-callable function.
key is a key sequence; noninteractively, it is a string or vector
of characters or event types, and non-ASCII characters with codes
above 127 (such as ISO Latin-1) can be included if you use a vector.
```

And for `(define-key)`

```
(define-key keymap key def)

In keymap, define key sequence key as def.
keymap is a keymap.

key is a string or a vector of symbols and characters meaning a
sequence of keystrokes and events.  Non-ASCII characters with codes
above 127 (such as ISO Latin-1) can be included if you use a vector.
Using [t] for key creates a default definition, which applies to any
event type that has no other definition in this keymap.
```